# Submitting form-data via axios fails with dataSize=0

Tags: node.js, axios, form-data

I'm using the `form-data` npm package to send a list of images from my server (node/express) to another server. I'm using axios to send the form data.

The way I'm getting the list of images is getting them from a URL in a blob format and attaching them to form data like so: `formData.append('pictures[]', picture)`.

Trouble is that in *some* cases when I try to submit the form data to another server, I'm getting this error below. Thing is that this doesn't happen in all cases, that's what's weird about all this.

```
{
  "message": "Request failed with status code 500",
  "name": "Error",
  "stack": "Error: Request failed with status code 500n    at createError (/app/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)n    at settle (/app/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)n    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/app/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:293:11)n    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:525:35)n    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:domain:489:12)n    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)n    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)",
  "config": {
    "transitional": {
      "silentJSONParsing": true,
      "forcedJSONParsing": true,
      "clarifyTimeoutError": false
    },
    "transformRequest": [
      null
    ],
    "transformResponse": [
      null
    ],
    "timeout": 0,
    "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
    "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
    "maxContentLength": null,
    "maxBodyLength": null,
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------505025809634644491355142",
      "User-Agent": "axios/0.24.0"
    },
    "method": "post",
    "url": "<some url here>",
    "data": {
      "_overheadLength": 375,
      "_valueLength": 136604,
      "_valuesToMeasure": [],
      "writable": false,
      "readable": true,
      "dataSize": 0,
      "maxDataSize": 2097152,
      "pauseStreams": true,
      "_released": true,
      "_streams": [],
      "_currentStream": null,
      "_insideLoop": false,
      "_pendingNext": false,
      "_boundary": "--------------------------505025809634644491355142",
      "_events": {},
      "_eventsCount": 1
    }
  },
  "status": 500
}
```

As you can see from the error, `dataSize` is 0, which is totally unexpected. I put a few images in there.

Anyone experiences this before or can point me to resources which can help me debug this?

---

Here is the code to add all images to form data:

```
const form = new FormData()
let promises = []
for (let i = 0; i < pictureUrls.length; i++) {
  promises.push(axios.get(pictures[i], {responseType: 'blob'}));
}
Promise.all(promises).then(values => {
  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    form.append('pictures[]', values[i].data);
  }
})
```

Here is the code I'm using to send the images:

```
axios.post(URL, form, {auth, headers: form.getHeaders(), maxContentLength: Infinity, maxBodyLength: Infinity }
```

Comment: Do you have access to the server that replies with 500 to find out, why? Can you check that the retrieval of the images went well before submitting them?

Comment: @some-user I check that I get the images successfully. In the code example I left out the piece that checks the status of `axios.get` (to be 200).

I do not have direct access to the server, but people who do tell me that the issue should be on my side.

Comment: Even if the response code is 200, the response could be empty... I would not rely on the code alone.

Comment: @some-user I also get in response content length: eg `'content-length': '253333',`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you simply just use built in fetch instead of using axios (require NodeJS v18)

NodeJS have built in support for fetch, FormData and Blobs.
But they don't support getting file/blobs backed up by the filesystem yet <sup>[[1]](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/37340)</sup>

But there FormData implementation supports 3rd party Blob implementations. hence why I recommend you to install [fetch-blob](https://github.com/node-fetch/fetch-blob)

```js
import { fileFromSync } from 'fetch-blob/from.js'

// In case you are using CommonJS
// const { fileFromSync } = await import('fetch-blob/from.js')

const file = fileFromSync('package.json')
const fd = new FormData()
const res = await fetch('https://httpbin.org/post', { 
  method: 'POST', 
  body: fd 
})
const json = await res.json()
```

it knows how to serilize and setting the correct request headers with boundary.

Comment: I'm just trying to do this today! I seem to have solved some of the problems, but reintroduced some back.

Comment: Thing is that I'm getting the file from URL. So now I'm using `fetch(urlOfImage)`.

Comment: Does fetch-blob support getting images from a URL?

Comment: in that case you should do `fetch(imageUrl).then(res => res.blob()).then(blob => fd.set('field', blob, filename))`

Comment: Isn't something missing with this? You get the file from `fileFromSync()` but then don't add it to the `FormData()` which you appear to just be sending in as empty `FormData` in the body... unless I'm seriously missing something and need to fix my brain which is entirely possible haha...